# Transform rows categories to column while preserving rest of the data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have data frame as below

```
    Time    Groups  Entity  GC  Seg Category    Year    Quarter IndicatorName   Value
0   2021-06-01  KRO CO  P_GA    None    Model_Q2_2021   2021    2           yhat    568759.481223
1   2021-07-01  KRO CO  P_GA    None    Model_Q2_2021   2021    3           yhat    586003.965652
2   2021-08-01  KRO CO  P_GA    None    Model_Q2_2021   2021    3           yhat    583703.420655
3   2021-09-01  KRO CO  P_GA    None    Model_Q2_2021   2021    3           y       608601.857510
4   2021-10-01  KRO CO  P_GA    None    Model_Q2_2021   2021    4           y       628928.602344
```

I want to `IndicatorName` categories to make them columns in such a way that the corresponding value to them in addtion to the rest of the columns

I tried `pivot`, and `melt` but nothing gave me desired results.

The closed I have gone was with this

```
grouper = df.groupby('IndicatorName')
out = pd.concat([pd.Series(v['Value'].tolist(), name=k) for k, v in grouper], axis=1)

         y      yhat
0   8626.88 5.687595e+05
1   8215.30 5.860040e+05
2   8601.53 5.837034e+05
3   8145.16 6.086019e+05
4   9376.81 6.289286e+05
... ... ...
744 NaN 5.402358e+06
745 NaN 5.796123e+06
746 NaN 5.218829e+06
747 NaN 5.451504e+06
```

But I want to have all columns preserved and additional columns `yhat` and `y`

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected output for your input dataframe?

Comment: all columns from original data frame and values columns should be allocated to yhat and y

Comment: Do you want to pivot `IndicatorName` as columns with `Value` as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `pivot_table`:

```
>>> (df.pivot_table(index=df.columns[:-2].tolist(), columns=['IndicatorName'], values='Value')
       .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))

        Time Groups Entity    GC   Seg       Category  Year  Quarter              y           yhat
0 2021-06-01    KRO     CO  P_GA  None  Model_Q2_2021  2021        2            NaN  568759.481223
1 2021-07-01    KRO     CO  P_GA  None  Model_Q2_2021  2021        3            NaN  586003.965652
2 2021-08-01    KRO     CO  P_GA  None  Model_Q2_2021  2021        3            NaN  583703.420655
3 2021-09-01    KRO     CO  P_GA  None  Model_Q2_2021  2021        3  608601.857510            NaN
4 2021-10-01    KRO     CO  P_GA  None  Model_Q2_2021  2021        4  628928.602344            NaN
```

You can change `[:-2]` by `[:-1]` if you want to keep the `IndicatorName` column.

Answer (score 0):

add the two columns you want, and fill them with the value of `df['value']` with a condition based on the value of `df['IndicatorName']`:

```
df['yhat'] = df['Value']*(df['IndicatorName'] == 'yhat')
df['y'] = df['Value']*(df['IndicatorName'] == 'y')
```

should get you:

```
    Time        (...) IndicatorName        Value      yhat         y
0   2021-06-01  (...)          yhat    568759.48 568759.48         0
1   2021-07-01  (...)          yhat    586003.96 586003.96         0
2   2021-08-01  (...)          yhat    583703.42 583703.42         0
3   2021-09-01  (...)             y    608601.85         0 608601.85
4   2021-10-01  (...)             y    628928.60         0 628928.60
```